# Can this algorithm be made more efficient?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Currently I have an algorithm that runs to compare to different arrays of objects.

```
const allGroups = [{ id: '12345', name: 'groupOne'}, {id: '23421', name: 'groupTwo'},
{id: '28182', name: 'groupThree'}]


const clientsGroups = [{ id: 'abcde', clientGroupID: '12345'}, {id: 'dfcdae', clientGroupID: '93282'},
{id: 'jakdab', clientGroupID: '28182'}, {id: 'oiewad', clientGroupID: '93482'}]

const updateClientGroups = (allGroups, clientsGroups) => {
  let allGroupsCopy = [...allGroups];
  for (let i = 0; i < allGroupsCopy.length; i++) {
    const allGroupsId = allGroupsCopy[i].id;
    for (let j = 0; j < clientsGroups.length; j++) {
      if (allGroupsId === clientsGroups[j].clientGroupID) {
        allGroupsCopy[i] = {
          ...allGroupsCopy[i],
          inGroup: true,
          clientGroupID: clientsGroups[j].id,
        };
      }
    }
  }
  return allGroupsCopy;
};
```

I check two different arrays of objects, if the *id* of **allGroups** matches the *clientGroupID* of **clientGroups**, I mutate the 'allGroupsCopy' to have 'inGroup: true' and add in the *id* of the **clientsGroups**.

The problem with this algorithm is it runs in n^2 time. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: The copying of allGroups is probably superfluous, if you don't have profiler data suggesting otherwise simply doing a `.push` is better. Overall you could hash clientGroups by id for O(1) search rather than O(n) search for the id match, but you'd need to time it to see if the work converting the array to an object outweights the gains. At the very least add a break statement after the match is found so you don't iterate the rest of the clientGroups array every time. The real question is a) do you have enough data that it matters and b) if so why aren't you aggregating in your database in SQL?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll definitely add the break in for now. The reason I made a copy is because allGroups is a redux state. I guess it doesn't matter too much in terms of the amount of data, but I may have a similar problem down the line where the # of items starts increasing faster. The reason for this problem is because I'm using AWS Amplify, which stores join tables in a separate table, and this is the only way (at least that I've found) to figure out whether an item is already part of the join table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the original arrays, could this be the an optimization ?

```
const allGroups = [
  { id: "12345", name: "groupOne" },
  { id: "23421", name: "groupTwo" },
  { id: "28182", name: "groupThree" },
];

const clientsGroups = [
  { id: "abcde", clientGroupID: "12345" },
  { id: "dfcdae", clientGroupID: "93282" },
  { id: "jakdab", clientGroupID: "28182" },
  { id: "oiewad", clientGroupID: "93482" },
];

const updateClientGroups = (groups, clients) => {
  return clients.reduce((acum, current) => {
    const isInGroup = groups.find((group) => group.id === current.clientGroupID);

    acum.push({
      ...current,
      inGroup: Boolean(isInGroup),
    });

    return acum;
  }, []);
};

updateClientGroups(allGroups, clientsGroups)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change `allGroups` structure from array to map, you can do the job in linear time.
Something like:

```
const allGroups = {
    '12345': { id: '12345', name: 'groupOne'}
    ...
}
const updateClientGroups = (allGroups, clientsGroups) => {
  const clientGroupsMap = {};
  clientsGroups.forEach(({clientGroupID}) => 
     if(allGroups[clientGroupID]) {
         clientGroupsMap[clientGroupID] = {...allGroups[clientGroupID], inGroup: true};
     }
  );
  return {...allGroups, ...clientGroupsMap};
};
```